# Forward CNAME to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, dns, openshift

I have a OpenShift instance with DIY cartridge, where I personally configured Apache Tomcat. Here is my `server.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="15005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" address="OPENSHIFT_DEV_IP">

 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

 <GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="jdbc_ttDS" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
            url="jdbc:h2:ssutt;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM './initTT.sql'"

            username="####"
            password="####"
            maxActive="20"
            maxIdle="5"
            maxWait="-1"
            description="SSU TT database"
            />  

<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
   </GlobalNamingResources>

 <Service name="Catalina">


<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           address="OPENSHIFT_DEV_IP"
           redirectPort="15443" />
<Connector port="15009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" address="OPENSHIFT_DEV_IP"/>


<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="OPENSHIFT_DEV_IP">

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="backend-ssutt.rhcloud.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>

 </Engine>
 </Service>
</Server>
```

I can access it via `backend-ssutt.rhcloud.com`. That's ok. Strangely, I can't access it via some other address like `api.ssutt.org`, however I added alias for instance and DNS CNAME record.

Strangely, it was working on default Tomcat 7/EWS cartridge. How can I configure Tomcat or my DNS records to be accessible via some other address.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding `Alias` to Tomcat config.[Official documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Host%20Name%20Aliases)